# Sockets: Non-blocking shutdown(SHUT_WR)?

Tags: sockets, nonblocking, shutdown

Is there a way to do shutdown(SHUT_WR) on socket asynchronously?

I.e. start the operation, then wait for its completion using poll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's asynchronous anyway. It just queues a FIN behind the current contents of the socket send buffer, if any, which really just amounts to setting a bit somewhere. There's no `poll()` operation for completion of any send, let alone this one.

Comment: Is there any reference supporting that?

Comment: @user2694310 RFC 793.